# How do I setup ui-router to allow views inheritance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, angular-ui-router

How do I setup ui-router to allow views inheritance? Currently, I have my ui-router setup similar to as follows,

```
$stateProvider

            .state('public', {
                url: '/public',
                templateUrl: 'partials/public.html',
                controller: 'PublicController'
            })

            // abstract parent
            .state('private', {
                abstract: true,
                views: {
                    '': { 
                        template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
                    },

                    'nav': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/nav.html'
                    }
                }
            })

            // concrete private child state
            .state('private.pageone', {
                url: '/pageone',
                views: {
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/pageone.html',
                        controller: 'PageOneCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })
```

Everything is running fine, except that the parent `nav` view is not being inherited, and so I can't see the `nav` in the child state display. On the other hand, if I get rid of the parent state and then move the `nav` view directly to the child state... I can display the `nav`. Can anybody explain to me why I can't seem to be able to inherit the `nav`, even though the child is specified as `private.pageone` (same as `parent: 'private'`).

Comment: Could you please post the HTML template where you have these `views` referenced (`nav` for example)? It looks a bit weird that you don't have a name for that view before`nav`.

Comment: @ex0dm3nt I can post the HTML, but I don't quite understand your concern. What do you mean by "view before nav"?

Comment: `'': { 
                        template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
                    }` - this one, where is it referenced, in your HTML template?

Comment: @ex0dm3nt I was forced to add that in. If I remove it, my child is not displayed at all! It seems that it is the template that hosts the child.

Comment: @ex0dm3nt Oh and just in case you are wondering, nameless views basically reference `<ui-view></ui-view>` as opposed to a named one `<div ui-view="named-view"></div>`

Comment: That's basically what I'm getting at. Do you have the same thing set up for `nav` as well, for example `<div ui-view="nav"></div>`? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views - on the bottom of this page there is a setup that is similar to yours.

Comment: @ex0dm3nt Yes I do. `<div ui-view="nav"></div>` is specified within `pageone.html`.

Comment: I'm not sure that is a correct setup. You have a placeholder for `nav` view defined in your child state's template (`pageone.html`), but it should be wherever the main `<ui-view></ui-view>` is referenced. You said it yourself, nav is only working when you remove it from parent and move it to the child state. Try moving the `<div ui-view="nav"></div>` to the parent state as well.

Comment: @ex0dm3nt Got it! Thanks.

Comment: @ex0dm3nt I tried that, however... unless I say `nav@private` I can't get the `nav` to be displayed. I mean within the `private` state... after having moved the `<div ui-view="nav"></div>` to the `private` state as well. Why is that? I thought one should be able to simply say `nav` as the view and make it relative so that the children could also inherit.

Comment: I'm not really sure without looking at all of the code. However, it could be that your parent state is `abstract` and as such it cannot be navigated to and active the `nav` view. You can find additional info on abstract states here : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#abstract-states

Comment: @ex0dm3nt Turns out it is nothing to do with being abstract or not.

Comment: @ex0dm3nt Thanks for you help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) mention that relative views actually target the template in the parent state. So to be able to use relative views in this particular situation we would have to do the following.

```
$stateProvider

        .state('public', {
            url: '/public',
            templateUrl: 'partials/public.html',
            controller: 'PublicController'
        })

        // abstract parent
        .state('private', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                '': { 
                    template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
                }
            }
        })

        // concrete private child state
        .state('private.pageone', {
            url: '/pageone',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/pageone.html',
                    controller: 'PageOneCtrl'
                },

                // target the <div ui-view="nav"></div> in the parent template
                'nav': {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/nav.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

Alternatively, it would be possible to use absolute views instead of relative ones, as in the following.

```
$stateProvider

            .state('public', {
                url: '/public',
                templateUrl: 'partials/public.html',
                controller: 'PublicController'
            })

            // abstract parent
            .state('private', {
                abstract: true,
                views: {
                    '': { 
                        template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
                    },

                    // note how nav has been specified absolutely
                    'nav@private': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/nav.html'
                    }
                }
            })

            // concrete private child state
            .state('private.pageone', {
                url: '/pageone',
                views: {
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/pageone.html',
                        controller: 'PageOneCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })
```